# How I can turn off unknown webserver (Apache probably)?

Tags: 10.04, apache2, webserver, xampp

I want to start XAMPP Apache server but it terminal it says that another web server daemon is already running. So I want to find out how to turn off it or so.

When I go to localhost I get following message:

> It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

When I go to localhost/index.php I get this message:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

But it worked when I was starting XAMPP Apache and going to localhost earlier, it would open my index.php page and now I can't start it.

I'm not sure if that webserver is Apache, but I'm just telling what happens when I go to localhost

So what I should do? I am using Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well XAMPP is an all in one package which brings its own apache with it. But Ubuntu has all these packages in its main repository, so I would suggest you opt to use Ubuntu packages to setup your server (There are How-To's online, e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

Another option is to remove the Ubuntu provided Apache:

```
sudo aptitude purge apache2
```

You can then try to start XAMPP again and connect to your local webserver.

Comment: @Thomas, I think Ubuntu 10.04 doesnt use upstart scripts for apache.

Try `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop` instead

Comment: But one week ago everything was fine, and I was just starting XAMPP and it worked, so it means something happened, maybe I installed something or so

Comment: The command `sudo aptitude purge apache2` should remove those packages (sorry, I forgot the two at the end)

Comment: sudo service apache2 stop worked

Comment: This stopped your apache2 service. You will have the problem again when you reboot your system next time. You can permanently remove Ubuntu's apache using `sudo aptitude purge apache2`...

Comment: ok I will see but as I told week ago there wasn't such problem

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo service apache stop
```

You might try to remove the apache package.

Comment: I get apache: unrecognized service maybe it's not apache I don't know

Comment: I is apache - see the error message you get when you try to get localhost/index.php. The servie name could be apache2 - take a look at /etc/init.d/ to find out.

Comment: yeah sudo service apache2 stop worked and now I started XAMPP and everything's fine

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```